# Sending Full Master data objects of DEBMAS from change pointer

Tags: abap, sap-erp, idoc

I need to send complete DEBMAS and complete MATMAS idoc to my other system. I'm able to create and send MATMAS and DEBMAS idocs on change but it only sends the changed (delta) data. So I have made an enhancement on FM: CHANGE_POINTERS_READ which is like this:

```
ENHANCEMENT 1  ZSEND_COMPLETE_IDOCS.    "active version

  field-symbols <fs_bdcp> type bdcp.

  if message_type = 'DEBMAS' or message_type = 'MATMAS'.

    loop at change_pointers assigning <fs_bdcp>.

      <fs_bdcp>-fldname = 'ALELISTING'.

    endloop.
  endif.

ENDENHANCEMENT.
```

However this only works for MATMAS. When I change a material in MM02, my idoc is created with complete segments, not only with changed segments. However this enhancement does not work for DEBMAS!?!? Anyone knows why?

I need to find out how to send my DEBMAS idoc completely to my other system.

Thanks in advance.

Talha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by myself. You need to use `BD12` tcode in order to send complete idoc of `DEBMAS`, other ways are not working correctly.